Solving sparse bilinear systems with a relatively large number of variables
I'm trying to solve a bilinear system of equations over a finite field. (More specifically: I'm trying to find a single solution, if one exists.) The system consists of equations of the form
$$y^T A_i x = b_i$$
for $i = 1, \ldots, m$. Here $x$ and $y$ are unknown vectors of length $p$, $A_i$ is a $p$-by-$p$ matrix, and $b_i$ is a scalar. The number of variables is relatively large in the sense that $p$ and $m$ are roughly the same size, so $p^2$ is typically much larger than $m$.
I've tried to solve the system by using Gröbner bases and elimination theory, but this approach (or at least my implementation of elimination theory) quickly becomes very inefficient as the number of variables increases. I've also read the paper Solution Theory for Systems of Bilinear Equations, which describes how one can solve a bilinear system by reducing it to a quadratic system of equations. However, this quadratic system would have ${p \choose 2}^2$ equations and $p^2 - m$ variables, which in this case is much larger than the $m$ equations and $2p$ variables of the original bilinear system, so it doesn't seem like this approach would make the system much easier to solve.
However, the system does have some additional structure that may make it easier to solve:

The matrices $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ are linearly independent, and are typically quite sparse. In fact, they have disjoint support, in the sense that if $A_i$ has a nonzero entry in position $(j, k)$, then none of the other matrices have a nonzero entry in the same position. (In other words, each monomial $y_j x_k$ appears in at most one equation.)
$%Consider mentioning redundancy$
The matrices $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ tend to look similar to each other, in the following sense: there exists a fixed matrix $M$ such that each $A_i$ is of the form $$A_i = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & B_i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
where $B_i$ is either an identity matrix, or a matrix that can be obtained from $M$ by removing some of its rows and columns. The zeroes in the above matrix denote zero blocks of varying width and height.

Is there an algorithm that can solve this kind of bilinear system relatively efficiently?
